# Deriving a formula for an estimator of a population mean

Tags: statistics

How do I derive a formula for an estimator of a given population mean? I am supposed to know how to do this for a test, but haven't come across any examples of this.

Also, isn't the formula below supposed to be the estimator for population mean? Does deriving a formula mean that I have to show how I got this formula or come up with a different formula for it?

$$\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n}\Sigma^ny_i$$

So, it would be really helpful if someone could give me an example doing this or guide me through it.

Comment: Your formula is for the _sample_ mean $\bar Y = (1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ of observations $Y_1, \dots, Y_n.$ For some population distributions, the sample mean is the 'best' estimate of the population mean $\mu$, and for others not the 'best'. For a normal population, best; for a population distributed $Unif(0, 2\mu),$ not best. We need context to give an answer at an appropriate level. Are you in a math stat course where method of moments and max. likelihood estimators are covered? If not, can you give a clue what it means to 'derive' an estimator $\hat \mu$ for $\mu?$ Any criterion for 'best'?

Comment: @BruceET I'm taking a stats course that's focused on surveys and sampling. We haven't talked about any kind of distributions like the uniform distribution.

Comment: OK then. Any clue what it means to 'derive' an estimator? Do they intend you to 'compute' a mean from data? Do they intend you to 'derive' a formula for data in 'frequency-value' form? (If there are five 0's, seven 1's, eight 2's and six 3's, then what is the average? E.g.: $[5(0) + 7(1) + 8(2) + 6(3)]/[5+7+8+6].$ In general $\bar Y = \sum_{j = 1}^K f_jv_j/\sum_{j=1}^K f_j,$ where there are $K$ values $v_j$ with respective frequencies $f_j.$

Comment: @BruceET It just says what my questions asks for. I also need to derive a formula for an estimator of the standard error of the estimated
mean, $s_y=\sqrt var(\bar{Y})$. And "the correct solution is a variant of the derivation for the
general case". I don't really know what it means to derive a formula since I've never done it before.

Comment: I suppose it is completely out of the question to ask the instructor....